# Why is the Microsoft Access Linked Table Manager not updating a linked *text* file to different file name?

Tags: ms-access

In Microsoft Access 2010 I am attempting to change a **linked text file** to point to a similar file with a **different file name**. However, after relinking to the new file, I discovered that my linked table was *still pointing to the original text file*.

Here are the steps I was taking:

[image]

I open the Linked Table Manager, then browse to the new file name...

[image]

After selecting the new file, I receive the following message that everything is good to go!

[image]

However the linked table is ***still pointing to the old file!***

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is it expected that this would work differently for text files, and require deleting and recreating the linked table?

In VBA I can automate the relink, but it just seems odd that the wizard would not function consistently between different types of linked tables. (For example, I can use this same process to change the link to an Excel worksheet in a different file, and it relinks just fine to the new file.)

Comment: I attempted this and get error message that the original filename cannot be found in the new folder location. Will not refresh link unless the filename is the same. I really don't see how you can get as far as you do unless you are actually browsing to the original folder location.

Comment: @June7 - In my case (Access 2010) I don't get any errors if the structure of the file is the same. (Matching the import spec.) To test this, you might trying saving an Excel spreadsheet as text, then renaming a copy of the text file and changing some of the content. Then you could link to the first file, and attempt to change the link to the second file. That would probably give you a similar result as what I am describing above... Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: May I ask why this question was downvoted with no explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should compare this with other linked tables (MS Access of MS SQL Server). What you can choose using the *Linked Table Manager* isn't another table but another database, the table names must be the same. Linked text files must be seen as tables, their containing folder must be seen as the database.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation really helped. This would go along with the actual wording in the Linked Table Manager... I am choosing a **new location**, not a new file (or *table*, as it may be better understood).